# Poco::Path compiles with const wchar_t* but behaves unexpectedly

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, wstring

Working with [`Poco::Path`](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Path.html) I've found a very curious error. See following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Poco/Path.h>

int main()
{
  std::wstring a_path = L"c:\\temp";

  //Poco::Path from_wstring(a_path); // ERROR: fails to compile, expected
  Poco::Path from_wchar_t(a_path.c_str()); // compiles... unexpected

  std::cout << from_wchar_t.toString() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But the output of the above program is (in Windows):

> \

instead of the expected:

> c:\temp

Reviewing the `Poco::Path` documentation I see no constructor expecting `std::wstring` (that's why the first path fails) nor `const wchar_t*`, only from `std::string` and `const char*` (both UTF-8).

How is it compiling with `const wchar_t*` and why the unexpected output (wrong path)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this question I figured out the problem. I've decided to document it here in case it is helpful for somebody else.

The code snippet shown in the question is part of a huge project so I was missing a compilation warning:

> warning C4800: 'const wchar_t *' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

Then I realized that there is a constructor `Poco::Path::Path(bool absolute)` and that the compiler was making the cast from pointer to bool automatically, producing then the unexpected behavior. The `\` of the output corresponds to an empty absolute path, its initial value when using such constructor.

---

For those interested in a workaround, I'm now using a UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion:

```
#include <boost/locale/encoding.hpp>
// ...
std::wstring a_path = L"c:\\temp";
Poco::Path utf8_path(boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(a_path));
```

Comment: For future reference: all POCO interfaces (except, obviously, the conversion ones) expect UTF-8 strings. Any conversions are taken care of internally, if needed.